# Why no singular when referring to one parent in the birchat hamazon?

Tags: bentching

Near the end of the birchat hamazon there is wording for a sentence for eating at the table of one's parents.  (See the left side of the quote below).  That sentence refers to "them, their house, their family, and all that is theirs".  But some people have only one living parent.  Why is there no wording suitable for someone eating at the table of their widowed mother or widower father (i.e., in the singular)?

(Related but different question: [Why no singular in birchat hamazon for "ours and all that is ours"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109439/why-no-singular-in-birchat-hamazon-for-ours-and-all-that-is-ours))

For example, from Artscroll pg 192:
[image: from Artscroll pg 192]

Comment: @Yehuda they can't include all the options as the options are endless הרחמן הוא יברך מורי בעל הבית הזה וזרעו וזקנתי בעלת הבית הזה וכל אשר לה ובעל הבית הזה האחר ואשתו ואמי מורתי וכל אשר לה ובעלי וזרעי וכל אשר לי for a house owned by your male unmarried teacher who has children, your non-teacher grandmother who, c"v, has no living children but has other property, and a third male owner who has a non-owner wife but no children, and also to include your mother and what she has and your own husband and children.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be having difficulty with the middle of the fourth bracha of the Birkhat Hamazon due to your level of Hebrew comprehension. An interlinear bencher or siddur, such as the Artscroll Simchat Yehoshua series, would provide you with word-for-word English text so you could adapt your benching to the situation at hand. Please see picture below to see how it works [image: relevant page of the Artscroll Simchat Yehoshua Sabbath and Festival Interlinear Siddur]

Comment: The instructions say "All continue" (in capital letters) and the wording that follows is in the plural, even if you are eating alone.  How does that make sense?

Comment: Excellent question, Yehuda. See the reference to the 3 patriarchs? From the "all continue" line on it's referring to Am Yisrael as a whole rather than the particular cicrumstance of where one or more Jews ate

Comment: Would that more people try to carefully understand the words they say.  In my experience, many truly learned people make mistakes in pronunciation, some of which change the meaning drastically. One common example is in Shalom Alechem on friday nights, when they happily sing about the angel of kings rather than the King of kings.

Comment: Amen, @Yehuda. The power of the spoken word is one of the basic principles of Judaism, and there are people who run ramshod over it on a daily basis

Comment: The 3 patriarchs are only mentioned after "ours and all that is ours" so that is not a solution to the issue I raised.

Comment: Yehuda, my understanding of that section is that one says it as part of Am Yisrael (just as in the beginning of the fourth blessing we refer to "Yaakov Roainu ("our shepard"), Roay Yisrael" even when benching alone)